# Trying to align the text area and the button side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Moving the button]

```html
   <form class="container">
      <div class="row">
      
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2>Template</h2>
            <textarea id="template" value={this.state.value1} placeholder=" Hello {{name}}! {% if test -%} How are you?{%- endif %}" onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}/>
            
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5">
         <h2>Render</h2>
         <div id="render"> {this.state.loading || !this.state.data ? < div id="render"></div> : <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}</div>}
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5">
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="convert" value="Convert" onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}/>
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" onClick={this.resetForm}/>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I am trying to move the button to the right side of the grey box so that all text box  and button is horizontal to each other.

Tried to do inline block on the div class col-md-5 but it shifts everything vertical.

Here is the css:

```
h2{
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: normal;
}


ul{
    list-style-type: none;

}
.col-md-5{
     margin: auto;
}
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }


#template,
#render,
#values {

     width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

}



#render {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using bootstrap, you need to make sure your totals add up to 12. md-5 * 3 = 15 so it would force it to next line.  Try making your last div col-md-2

Comment: @Jim see comments below on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `col-md-5` for the buttons' container div.

One row consists of 12 columns in the bootstrap

You have to change it to `col-md-2` or reduce the size of textarea's container div

If `col-md-2` does not work, make sure to reset your defualt css

```
* { margin: 0 padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the button is still stuck to the bottom of the text box.  I added the css to the question.

Comment: @Jim That's because your button exceeds the width given by col-md-2. reduce the button size and change its display to block. Another option is to reduce the size of textarea's container and scale-up the buttons' div container. that will work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, You need to close your textarea tag as well. It is not self closing.

```
    <form class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Template</h2>
                <textarea id="template" value={this.state.value1} placeholder=" Hello {{name}}! {% if test -%} How are you?{%- endif %}" onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}> </textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Render</h2>
                <div id="render"> {this.state.loading || !this.state.data ? < div id="render"></div> : <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}</div>}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="convert" value="Convert" onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}/>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" onClick={this.resetForm}/>
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap goes by a 12 column system.  Your total adds up to 15 forcing the buttons to the next line.  Try changing the last column to the following:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="convert" value="Convert" onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}/>
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" onClick={this.resetForm}/>
         </div>
```

Comment: That did not work.  It shifted the buttons down and the box up.

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues with your code,

1. Second `div` with class `col-md-5` was not closed properly.
2. The sum of column numbers according to bootstrap guidelines should be 12 in a row (if you are following 12 column grid system).

This is the updated code that I think should solve it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>Template</h2>
    <textarea id="template" value={this.state.value1} placeholder=" Hello {{name}}! {% if test -%} How are you?{%- endif %}" onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>Render</h2>
    <div id="render"> {this.state.loading || !this.state.data ?
      <div id="render"></div> :
      <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}</div>}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="convert" value="Convert" onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}/>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" onClick={this.resetForm}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The sum of col-md-5 is going up to 15. You need to make your button as col-md-2 as commented above or you can make all of them as col-md-4.

```
   <form class="container">
  <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Template</h2>
        <textarea id="template" value={this.state.value1} placeholder=" Hello {{name}}! {% if test -%} How are you?{%- endif %}" onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}/>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
     <h2>Render</h2>
     <div id="render"> {this.state.loading || !this.state.data ? < div id="render"></div> : <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}</div>}
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="convert" value="Convert" onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}/>
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" onClick={this.resetForm}/>
     </div>
  </div>
```